# zend debugger can not be installed in wamp

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I am trying to install zend debugger in wamp in windows 7.but it could not be found in phpinfo().

**I have the following system in my phpinfo().**

php version : 5.5.12  ; Configuration File (php.ini) Path : C:\Windows
; Loaded Configuration File ; C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini ; Thread safety  : enabled

*****Till now I did the steps to install zend debugger*****
1. download zend studio from http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads.

2. Extracted the zip file. After extraction it contains a folder name "ZendDebugger-cygwin_nt-vc11 " and again this folder has 2 subforlders(php-5.5.x and php-5.6.x), dummy.php and readme.txt. Each subfolder contains
   ZendDebugger.dll.
3. created a folder named 'zend' in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin.
4. next created a subfolder named 'php-5.5.12' in 'zend' folder.
5. copied ZendDebugger.dll from the subfolder php-5.5.x and paste it in 
   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\zend\php-5.5.12
6. now edited php.ini file(C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini).
   added the following at extreme end of php.ini code.(below xdebug    configuration)

   ```
   [Zend]
   ```

   zend_extension_ts="C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/bin/zend/php-5.5.12/ZendDebugger.dll"
   zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
   zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
7. now copied 'dummy.php' file from the extracted folder ' ZendDebugger-cygwin_nt-vc11 '. and paste it in c:/wamp/www
8. restarted the server.
9. open phpinfo(). but could not find zend debugger.

can anyone please help me?

one more thing. I have set up xdebug successfully in wamp. I can see the xdebug configuration in phpinfo().

Thank u in advance.